# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool server utilities
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white or transparent

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/ads/display/6005).

Answer (score 23):

[image: Bareos - Open Source Data Protection]

Comment: Bareos is an _actual_ open-source fork of Bacula, which has lately [turned its back on the community](http://www.bareos.org/en/faq/items/why_fork.html) in various ways, such as [removing AGPL code from their git repo and then trying to claim copyright infringement](http://www.bareos.org/en/faq/items/copyright_bacula_bareos.html) against people who used it.

Comment: Please remember to include a 1px solid border on any ad that has a white or transparent background on the edge.

Comment: @stevvve That wasn't listed in the image requirements! Please remember to add that to the list next year. :)

Comment: Oddly enough, it's in the specs on SO. Added to the specs here. Feel free to edit the border if it's not as perty as you'd like it to be.

Comment: Yeah, we purposely designed the ads to have a clean, no border look (I'm fine with the border, but it wasn't listed as a requirement or even mentioned until just now). If you want a border why not add it to the CSS and not rely on users? Also, how much time did you spend updating all these ads when 1 line of CSS could have fixed it?

Answer (score 23):

[image: Configuration Management]

Comment: Been meaning to do this one for a while, no time like the present right?

Answer (score 16):

[image: How to build, design and test the security of web applications and web services.]

Comment: Please remember to include a 1px solid border on any ad that has a white or transparent background on the edge.

Answer (score 14):

[image: FreeBSD - more than Creation]

Comment: Please remember to include a 1px solid border on any ad that has a white or transparent background on the edge.

Answer (score 10):

[image: nginx: high-performance web-server for accelerated web infrastructure]

Comment: Please remember to include a 1px solid border on any ad that has a white or transparent background on the edge.

Answer (score 10):

[image: IT Infrastructure Automation & Compliance]

Answer (score 9):

[image: The quieter you become, the more you are able to hear...]

Answer (score 5):

[image: lighttpd: fly light]

Comment: Keeping it going!

Comment: Please remember to include a 1px solid border on any ad that has a white background on the edge.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Barman - Backup and Recovery Manager for PostgreSQL]

Answer (score 0):

[image: vim'x rebirth for the 21st century]

Comment: Please remember to include a 1px solid border on any ad that has a white background on the edge.

Answer (score -2):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD kernel and userland source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx and regular expressions]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Question closing feed]

Comment: Subtly amusing, but no - not really in the spirit of the site. I'd hate to see someone take it seriously.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Teckids e.V. – Erkunden, Entdecken, Erfinden – Discover, Explore, Forge]

Comment: 1. [SF] is English Only (yes I know that's ethnocentric and all that, I didn't make the rule) 2. Studies pretty universally show technology has negative impact on kids. Most prominently at ages <2, but also up to age 16 (possibly older, though brain development slows greatly until stopping completely around 24). If you don't believe studies, the *smartest people in the world* are sending their kids to schools where *technology is forbidden*... That should *really* make you think twice before *deliberately* exposing kids to technology.

Comment: English only: that’s why I’ve started translating some of it. But the other thing is pretty much ridiculous. Studies show whatever they were paid to show, and while I agree that children in general should not be introduced to technology in a harmful way (which includes leaving them alone with it), there are kids technologically skilled more than the average adult, who can really shine in that field with just some guidance and encouragement. Also, the goal of Teckids is to have kids teach kids, with adults only being there to kickstart it (and to answer questions, organise, etc.).

Comment: @ChrisS, I'd be interested in hearing more about these studies. Ping me in chat next time I wander by?

Comment: @TRiG [Fool's Gold](http://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED445803) is a great read if you're interested in a concise guide to "education" for kids. It shines in explaining some misconceptions - the main two being 1. to be smart by age 18 you need to cram kids full of info starting very early. Technology gives people access to every bit of human knowledge and is a great tool for accessing knowledge; but cramming kids full of it is bad, and explained. 2. "Education" is in quotes because knowledge isn't the only reason kids are at school, there's a lot of other development going on as well, also explained.

Answer (score -4):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD kernel and userland source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx and regular expressions. BSD is Dying. Seeking Kernel and Userland Developers to Hack and Improve BSD UNIX. Qualifications: C (required), asm (a plus). No prior open-source experience necessary. Warning: it's not for the faint of heart!]

Comment: This is just as bad as the other ***3*** community ads you've proposed this year. Please stop, review the comments on the previous submissions, and try to address the issues before posting again.

Comment: @ChrisS, which comments are you talking about?  I don't see any comments of why they are being voted down by some people.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6005/community-promotion-ads-2014/6219?noredirect=1#comment12180_6048

Comment: Additional, these seem to be sites you are affiliated with. Trying to promote sites you are affiliated with requires minimal disclosure per the [help], and seems spamy regardless.

Answer (score -6):

[image: mdoc.su — short manual page URLs, a deterministic URL shortener for BSD manual pages, written in nginx.conf]

Comment: Too wordy, and uses the "whitespace is wasted space" approach to design.

Answer (score -6):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine, over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx, it is uber fast and has very short URLs.]

Answer (score -14):

[image: If your data is important to you, back it up!]

Comment: Not doing Bacula anymore...[they've gone rogue](http://www.bareos.org/en/faq/items/why_fork.html).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Ah. Lame. I just pulled it over because it got lots of votes last year.

Comment: <s>I'll probably make a BaReOS ad at some point.</s> Someone beat me to it. Crafty bastards. Bacula is still good software, but they haven't touched the open source edition since 2012. That's pretty weak.

Answer (score -18):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. As the Twitter selection still hasn't changed, this will probably be nuclearated in votes for the third year running.

Comment: WOOHOO! Let's see if we can embarrass StackBot by getting it to -10 this year! <Cut to interior, Stack Exchange datacenter. A question selection algorithm is trying to determine how to commit suicide as it has neither wrists to slit nor a neck around which to place a noose. Sad music is playing - or maybe it's the server with the failed hard drive plaintively beeping for attention....>

Comment: @voretaq7 I think we've broken a record this year.

Comment: Aww, why no love for Twitter?  "Nuclearated" three years in a row--that's pretty interesting.

Comment: @Zenexer: The twitter bot is pretty good at spotting questions that should be closed but that's not it's purpose.

Comment: @voretaq7 [Watch out, you have competition!](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/community-promotion-ads-2014/2550#2550)

Comment: @Gilles We clearly have a greater depth of hate for our twitter bot than you guys. It's OK though - we've had YEARS of hating the twitter bot to get good at this. You guys actually [liked](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/815/9363) yours not too long ago. You'll catch up :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 [Indeed](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/community-promotion-ads-2014/2550#2550), we've fully learnt to [despise the Twitter bot](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/community-promotion-ads-2014/2629#2629).